# Google Play Services Multiplayer Player's Connection

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

My problem is that i don't understand how to tell when player disconnected.

So my game includes 2 players, the game itself works, when one player leaves the game like intended or close the application in manager, everything is fine, but when one player let's say loses internet connection nothing happens. I tried that by disabling internet connection on one player's device.

When one player leaves the game `RoomStatusUpdateCallback` calls methods in this sequence : 1.`onDisconnectedFromRoom` 2.`onPeerLeft` 3.`onPeersDisconnected`, but when one playes loses internet connection nothing is called. I'd like to know when one players loses connection.

I believe there is something like `ConnectivityManager` so i can probably use this at one player's device, but how do the second player know that the first one lost connection when `RoomStatusUpdateCallback` doens't say  anything?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a player disconnects from a network connectivity or servers issue, the connection status of the participant doesn't change until you call to leave the room. You can just monitor the connection status of the participants inside the room using `RoomStatusUpdateListener` methods as follows when other player is disconnected:

1.`onDisconnectedFromRoom`
2.`onPeerLeft`
3.`onPeersDisconnected`

See full [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#handling_room_creation_errors) on handling room creation errors.

I think you can try to implement a **custom watcher timers** on the clients that will repeatedly ping other peers to see if they're still connected.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i'll look into it. Currently i actually did something like that,  i send message to the other client every one second, and if one client doesn't get the message for more than 10 seconds, other assumes that he got disconnected